# How to require CKEditor with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, ckeditor, browserify

following [this](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_package_managers) document I downloaded CKEditor with NPM. But, to my surprise, no instruction is given about how requiring what..

I tried

```
var CKEditor = require('ckeditor');
CKEditor.replace( 'editor' );
```

And

```
var CKEditor = require('ckeditor');
CKEditor.create( document.getElementById( 'editor' ) );
```

In fact, console.log(CKEditor) gives {}

I have no idea nor on what modules are exposed or how to refer to them.
Any help, please?
I'm using Gulp and Browserify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `require('ckeditor');` there will be a global variable `CKEDITOR` that you can use

```
require('ckeditor');
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
```

Comment: Ok. It works, thank you for your help. Editor is loading, but I alwalys get this console error: "Uncaught The editor instance "editor" is already attached to the provided element." I tried to change id from "editor" to "editor2" to avoid some automatic replacement, but still get this error.